# Combine expected and timeout in Junit

Tags: java, junit

I'm writing a test for a function and I want to combine the expected and timeout and I don't want to make the global timeout 
like :

```
@Rule
public Timeout globalTimeout= new Timeout(200);
```

My example:

```
    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    @Test(timeout = 200)
    public void lattesRequireMilk() throws InterruptedException {
        // given
        Cafe cafe = new Cafe();
        cafe.restockBeans(7);

        // when
        cafe.brew(Latte); 
        Thread.sleep(400);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ,i just found it sorry for my silly Question :

```
 @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class,timeout = 1000)
    public void lattesRequireMilk() {
        // given
        Cafe cafe = new Cafe();
        cafe.restockBeans(7);

        // when
        cafe.brew(Latte);
    }
```

Comment: Also take a look at ExpectedException (http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html). You can target only the line which is supposed to throw the exception (no false positives).